# Change single pixel color in openCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, colors, pixel

I am trying to read specific pixel-colors with openCV from a cv::mat, but i get different results for the same color. So i tried to test to write pixel colors, which results also in strange colors that differs from my input.
for reading pixel colors i use:

```
Mat dst;
struct  {
    Vec3b colorrgb[10];
} RGBscan;
int aktivy[11] = {0, 430, 200, 170, 140, 200, 420, 670, 725, 725, 670};
int aktivx[11] = {0, 50, 200, 480, 920, 1200, 1360, 1200, 880, 540, 220};
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    RGBscan.colorrgb[i] = dst.at<Vec3b>(aktivy[i], aktivx[i]);
    cout << "rgbcode: " << RGBscan.colorrgb[i] << "  x: " << aktivx[i] 
         << "  y: " << aktivy[i] << "\n";
};
```

though some of the pixels contain the same color in the cv::Mat dst i get different results in the command line.

Also, when i try so set the pixel to another color with:

```
dst.at<Vec3b>(436, 50) = 255, 255, 255;
dst.at<Vec3b>(437, 50) = 255, 255, 255;
dst.at<Vec3b>(438, 50) = 255, 255, 255;
dst.at<Vec3b>(439, 50) = 0, 0, 0;
dst.at<Vec3b>(440, 50) = 0, 0, 0;
```

i get a different color printed on the picture.
When i check the printed pixels with gimp, 
(255, 255, 255) is now: (255, 110, 110)
and (0, 0, 0) is: (0, 210, 210).

The original color of these pixels is in RGB (210, 210, 210).

I just don't get what i'm doing wrong. Appreciate your help! :)

Comment: C++ is not Python, try like: `dst.at<Vec3b>(436, 50) = Vec3b(255, 255, 255);`

Comment: As a sidenote, `RGBscan.colorrgb[10] = ...` is out of bounds.

Comment: your `RGBscan` is useless and wrong as you're reading out of bounds. You can use `std::vector<Vec3b> eventually`

Answer (score 1):

When you're assigning a new value with:

```
dst.at<Vec3b>(436, 50) = 255, 255, 255;
```

you're using [C++ comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Built-in_comma_operator).

To assign a new value, you should use:

```
dst.at<Vec3b>(436, 50) = Vec3b(255, 255, 255);
```

---

Also note that you're reading out of bounds when `i==10`:

```
RGBscan.colorrgb[i] = ... // out of bounds when i == 10
```

Comment: ok, i will work at my struct later. Now i tried dst.at<Vec3b>(436, 50) = Vec3b(255, 255, 255); but it does the same as dst.at<Vec3b>(436, 50) = 255, 255, 255; i also found out, that only the first value is changed. so when i use 1, 255, 255 the pixel gets the 1 set but not the 255, 255. What could be the cause?

Comment: Please provide a working example that shows this problem (see how to do a [mcve])

Comment: ok i minimized my code and tried some things. first of all, i get my picture from a GetDC, after it, it gets converted for cv::Mat use. When i first save the picture with iwrite("test.bmp", dst); and read it afterwards with dst2 = imread("test.bmp", IMREAD_ANYCOLOR); i can successfully change the pixels to my desired color. For conversion i use a bitmapinfoheader, the device context and some handlers (hdc & hbmp). With GetDIBits i get the src.data for my cv::Mat src. Something here isn't working well, i didn't figure it out yet.